# Merging python dictionary values by conditional referencing

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

So let's say I have two dictionaries, `bal` and `prices_eth`. I want to add a new key `bal[eth]`, which will contain the price of an asset if it matches a value in `prices_eth`. For example:

```
bal={
    u'POWR': 5.341, 
    u'GXS': 1.758285, 
    u'NEO': 20.1805
}
price={
    u'POWRETH': 0.00161001, 
    u'GXSETH': 0.00974900, 
    u'NEOETH': 0.09775400
}
```

Then I want to combine them so they would look like this

```
bal={
    u'POWR' : {
        "balance" : 5.341, 
        "eth price" : 0.0016100
}, 
    u'GXS': {
        "balance" : 1.758285, 
        "eth price" : 0.00974900
}, 
    u'NEO': {
            "balance" : 20.1805, 
            "eth_price" : 0.09775400
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's readable, but could you please use Python that does not produce Syntax Errors?

Comment: Also without any further explanation of how you arrive at your desired output it's completely arbitrary.

Comment: Pertinent question: Do all keys in `price` end with "ETH"?

Comment: I guess the issue is I don't know the correct way to ask the question.. I'm completely new to programming. All keys in `price` will end ETH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to iterate through the intersection of the keys and add the corresponding balance and price as an entry in a new dictionary. The intersection isn't necessary if you can guarantee that if a key exists in either of balance of price, it will exist in the other. As I cannot assume this from your question, you can use the intersection operation on the key sets to produce the common keys (`setA.intersection(setB)` or simply  `setA & setB`).

```
keyset = set(bal) & set(price)
```

Another problem is that your keys are not common names - the keys within the python dictonary have the suffic "ETH". If you want to perform the intersection check to only take items that a present in both dictionaries, you will need to make the keys of both dictionaries consistent. Easiest solution is to duplicate one dictionary, fixing the inconsistencies.

```
c_price = dict()
for key in price:
    c_price[key.replace("ETH", "")] = price[key]
```

or simply

```
c_price = { key.replace('ETH', ''): price[key] for key in price.keys() }
```

Now, with two dictionaries with common keys you can create a dictionary that merges the values for each key into an individual dictionary by iterating through the keyset and setting the values on a new dictionary.

```
keyset = set(bal) & set(price)
for key in keyset:
    combined[key] = {'bal' : bal[key, 'price' : price[key])}
```

or simply

```
combined = { key : {'bal' : bal[key], 'price' : price[key]} for key in keyset }
```

Comment: Just for clarification, should the keyset actually be what I have here?

`keyset = set(bal) & set(c_price)`

Just now starting to understand your answer and I think this will do it, but wanted to confirm that I should use the simplified keys for `price`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the value in they key to be a dictionary and iterate over the keys in both dictionarys.

```
bal_keys= list(bal.keys())
price_keys= list(price.keys())

for balKey, priceKey in zip(bal_keys, price_keys):
    if bal[balKey] == price[priceKey]:
        bal[balKey]= {"balance": bal[balKey], "eth price": price[priceKey]}
```